# disabled у кнопки при нажатии на чекбокс

Tags: jquery

Сделал, чтобы при нажатии на чекбокс disabled у кнопки убиралось, но как сделать, чтобы оно появлялось при повторном нажатии на чекбокс?

```
<form method="POST" action="/processes/registration_process.php">
    <input required type="text" name="login" placeholder="Логин"><br><br>
    <input required type="password" name="password" placeholder="Пароль" minlength="5"><br><br>
<label class="checkbox1"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="rememberMe">Я принимаю условия </label><a href="../agreement/agreement.php">Пользовательского соглашения</a>
    <input disabled class="registrationButton" type="submit" name="subimt" value="Зарегестрироваться">
</form>

$('document').ready( function () {
  $('.checkbox1').click(function () {
    $('.registrationButton').removeAttr('disabled');
  })
});
```

Comment: Не по клику делай это а по проверке состояния чекбокса, понял?

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич понял, просто у меня проблемы с if else в jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(".checkbox").on('change', function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $(".registrationButton").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
  else {
    $(".registrationButton").prop('disabled',true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="/processes/registration_process.php">
    <input required type="text" name="login" placeholder="Логин"><br><br>
    <input required type="password" name="password" placeholder="Пароль" minlength="5"><br><br>
<label class="checkbox1"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="rememberMe">Я принимаю условия </label><a href="../agreement/agreement.php">Пользовательского соглашения</a>
    <input disabled class="registrationButton" type="submit" name="subimt" value="Зарегестрироваться">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы как то так, я давно на js не писал ничего

```
 $('document').ready( function () {

    if $('.checkbox1').prop('checked') {
        $('.registrationButton').removeAttr('disabled');
      }, else {
       $('.registrationButton').attr('class','disabled')
      }
    });
```

Comment: к сожалению не работает :(